# X11 forwarding with an already running window?

Tags: linux, xorg, forwarding, x11-forwarding

I'm trying to forward the X session to my Windows laptop (using Xming and putty), and I have no problem opening new programs such as gedit and having them forward, but how would I forward something such as a Firefox window which is already open and running? I don't want to shut it down and restart it. Is there any way of forwarding something that's already running? And if so, can I "unforward" the X session without closing the program down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks for a program called `xmove`.  It's not usually installed by default, but should be available in your distro's package manager.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be in the repo anymore, and I can't seem to find it anywhere :S

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/source/browse/README.xpra claims that xmove has been unmaintained since 1997. Note that that is part of the xpra FAQ, so they have no incentive to look very hard for forks or anything. On the other hand xpra looks like a modern replacement for xmove, albeit still in beta.

Comment: Looks like there a newer program called [xpra](http://code.google.com/p/partiwm/wiki/xpra) that does the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Could use VNC.

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_remote_desktop_software

Comment: Yeah, VNC isn't very efficient or fast though, especially when I only want one window open. That and it has issues with multiple monitors moving to a single monitor setup.

Comment: Some versions of VNC have single-window support, but was just mentioning the answer for completeness. =)